# Embedded SSRS Subreport returns all rows instead of matching specified parameters for each parent row

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report with an embedded subreport.  The subreport takes two parameters.  I configured the Table Adapter for the subreport DataSet to accept two parameters.  When I test the standalone subreport, it works as expected.  However when embedded in the parent report the subreport returns all the rows in the table instead of the rows matching the parent row parameters.  I have configured the subreport to accept the two parameters from the parent row. I want the subreport to only return rows that match the parent row parameter values.  Am I missing a step or going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell SSRS how to relate the subreport to the main report:

- Right-click the subreport, select "Subreport properties"
- Select "Parameters" in the left panel
- Click "Add" and match your subreport field to a main report parameter